# Sending notifications at certain times (such as Facebook, instagram, twitter etc notification) in Java Android

Tags: android, android-studio

In the android application I will make, I will send notifications to the user at different time intervals. as follows; When the application is completely closed or in the background, or when the user is in the application, I want to send notifications to the user at intervals that I set. I'm new at this job. Can you help me with a code snippet? I can't speak English well. I hope I was able to explain my request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WorkManager`, `AlarmManager`, user specific Push Notifications via `FCM + Topic Subscription`?

Comment: @DarShan Yes....